# DataForm in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, telerik

It is just hard to find the way to build a dataform in MVC? like flipping CRUD operations without refreshing and that means AJAX on the page and load edit and create controls at same location.

If anyone have good idea about it. please share your thoughts.

I am looking like [Telerik DataForm](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dataform/data-editing/manual-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [Single Page Application](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application) template from Visual Studio makes it fairly easy to get started.  You use Entity Framework to work with your database model, and then the tooling will help you generate the controllers and views. You don't have to worry about manually coding any AJAX/javascript as the application will handle the communication between the client and server.